# Canvas/WebGL 2D tilemap grid artifacts

Tags: html5-canvas, 2d, webgl

I am creating a simple 2D web game that works with your typical tile map and sprites.

The twist is that I want smooth camera controls, both translation and scaling (zooming).

I tried using both the Canvas 2D API, and WebGL, and in both I simply cannot avoid the bleeding grid line artifacts, while also supporting zooming properly.

If it matters, all of my tiles are of size 1, and scaled to whatever size is needed, all of their coordinates are integers, and I am using  a texture atlas.

Here's an example picture using my WebGL code, where the thin red/white lines are not wanted.
[image]

I remember writing sprite tile maps years ago with desktop GL, ironically using similar code (more or less equivalent to what I could do with WebGL 2), and it never had any of these issues.

I am considering to try DOM based elements next, but I fear it will not feel or look smooth.

Comment: What is your question? Please post code to get help with your problem.

Comment: The question is how to not have artifacts.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. I'm sure someone would love to help, but without code it's not possible to do so.

Comment: I am sure someone who has experience with graphics, rendering, and perhaps OpenGL may help. Sure, I can attach the code that requires to render this, enjoy sifting through 2k lines of instanced rendering code. That being said, it's enough to draw two rects in the 2D context one next to the other, and use the scale and translate methods to move around using smooth float numbers.

Comment: It doesn't take 2k lines of code to make a sample that repos your issue

Comment: [This might be a useful reference](https://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to draw the tiles in the fragment shader

So you have your map, say a `Uint32Array`. Break it down into units of 4 bytes each. First 2 bytes are the tile ID, last byte is flags

As you walk across the quad for each pixel you lookup in the tilemap texture which tile it is, then you use that to compute UV coordinates to get pixels from that tile out of the texture of tiles. If your texture of tiles has gl.NEAREST sampling set then you'll never get any bleeding

Note that unlike traditional tilemaps the ids of each tile is the X,Y coordinate of the tile in the tile texture. In other words if your tile texture has 16x8 tiles across and you want your map to show the tile 7 over and 4 down then the id of that tile is 7,4 (first byte 7, second byte 4) where as in a traditional CPU based system the tile id would probably be 4*16+7 or 71 (the 71st tile). You could add code to the shader to do more traditional indexing but since the shader has to convert the id into 2d texture coords it just seemed easier to use 2d ids.

```js
const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  //attribute vec4 texcoord; - since position is a unit square just use it for texcoords

  uniform mat4 u_matrix;
  uniform mat4 u_texMatrix;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
    // v_texcoord = (u_texMatrix * texccord).xy;
    v_texcoord = (u_texMatrix * position).xy;
  }
`;

const fs = `
  precision highp float;

  uniform sampler2D u_tilemap;
  uniform sampler2D u_tiles;
  uniform vec2 u_tilemapSize;
  uniform vec2 u_tilesetSize;
  uniform vec2 u_tileUVMinBounds;
  uniform vec2 u_tileUVMaxBounds;

  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    vec2 tilemapCoord = floor(v_texcoord);
    vec2 texcoord = clamp(
       fract(v_texcoord), u_tileUVMinBounds, u_tileUVMaxBounds);
    vec2 tileFoo = fract((tilemapCoord + vec2(0.5, 0.5)) / u_tilemapSize);
    vec4 tile = floor(texture2D(u_tilemap, tileFoo) * 256.0);

    float flags = tile.w;
    float xflip = step(128.0, flags);
    flags = flags - xflip * 128.0;
    float yflip = step(64.0, flags);
    flags = flags - yflip * 64.0;
    float xySwap = step(32.0, flags);
    if (xflip > 0.0) {
      texcoord = vec2(1.0 - texcoord.x, texcoord.y);
    }
    if (yflip > 0.0) {
      texcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y);
    }
    if (xySwap > 0.0) {
      texcoord = texcoord.yx;
    }

    
    vec2 tileCoord = (tile.xy + texcoord) / u_tilesetSize;
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_tiles, tileCoord);
    if (color.a <= 0.1) {
      discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
`;

const tileWidth = 32;
const tileHeight = 32;
const tilesAcross = 8;
const tilesDown = 4;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('#c').getContext('webgl');

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// gl.createBuffer, bindBuffer, bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      0, 1,
      
      0, 1,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
    ],
  },
});

function r(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}

// make some tiles
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = tileWidth * tilesAcross;
ctx.canvas.height = tileHeight * tilesDown;
ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

const f = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~';
for (let y = 0; y < tilesDown; ++y) {
  for (let x = 0; x < tilesAcross; ++x) {
    const color = `hsl(${r(360) | 0},${r(50,100)}%,50%)`;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    const tx = x * tileWidth;
    const ty = y * tileHeight;
    ctx.fillRect(tx, ty, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.fillText(f.substr(y * 8 + x, 1), tx + tileWidth * .5, ty + tileHeight * .5); 
  }
}
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);

const tileTexture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
 src: ctx.canvas,
 minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

// make a tilemap
const mapWidth = 400;
const mapHeight = 300;
const tilemap = new Uint32Array(mapWidth * mapHeight);
const tilemapU8 = new Uint8Array(tilemap.buffer);
const totalTiles = tilesAcross * tilesDown;
for (let i = 0; i < tilemap.length; ++i) {
  const off = i * 4;
  // mostly tile 9
  const tileId = r(10) < 1 
      ? (r(totalTiles) | 0)
      : 9;
  tilemapU8[off + 0] = tileId % tilesAcross;
  tilemapU8[off + 1] = tileId / tilesAcross | 0;
  const xFlip = r(2) | 0;
  const yFlip = r(2) | 0;
  const xySwap = r(2) | 0;
  tilemapU8[off + 3] = 
    (xFlip  ? 128 : 0) |
    (yFlip  ?  64 : 0) |
    (xySwap ?  32 : 0) ;
}

const mapTexture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: tilemapU8,
  width: mapWidth,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

function ease(t) {
  return Math.cos(t) * .5 + .5;
}

function lerp(a, b, t) {
  return a + (b - a) * t;
}

function easeLerp(a, b, t) {
  return lerp(a, b, ease(t));
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds;
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);  

  const mat = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
  m4.scale(mat, [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 1], mat);
 
  const scaleX = easeLerp(.5, 2, time * 1.1);
  const scaleY = easeLerp(.5, 2, time * 1.1);
  
  const dispScaleX = 1;
  const dispScaleY = 1;
  // origin of scale/rotation
  const originX = gl.canvas.width  * .5;
  const originY = gl.canvas.height * .5;
  // scroll position in pixels
  const scrollX = time % (mapWidth  * tileWidth );
  const scrollY = time % (mapHeight * tileHeight);
  const rotation = time;
  
  const tmat = m4.identity();
  m4.translate(tmat, [scrollX, scrollY, 0], tmat);
  m4.rotateZ(tmat, rotation, tmat);
  m4.scale(tmat, [
    gl.canvas.width  / tileWidth  / scaleX * (dispScaleX),
    gl.canvas.height / tileHeight / scaleY * (dispScaleY),
    1,
  ], tmat);
  m4.translate(tmat, [ 
    -originX / gl.canvas.width,
    -originY / gl.canvas.height,
     0,
  ], tmat);

  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_matrix: mat,
    u_texMatrix: tmat,
    u_tilemap: mapTexture,
    u_tiles: tileTexture,
    u_tilemapSize: [mapWidth, mapHeight],
    u_tilesetSize: [tilesAcross, tilesDown],
    u_tileUVMinBounds: [0.5 / tileWidth, 0.5 / tileHeight],
    u_tileUVMaxBounds: [(tileWidth - 0.5) / tileWidth, (tileHeight -0.5) / tileHeight],
  });
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did ultimately figure it's actually the texture atlas sampling and not the geometry, at least in the case of my WebGL code (I doubt the Canvas 2D API automatically handles images with a texture atlas).

Comment: Also, indeed I have similar code, albeit mine uses instanced rendering. I do use nearest sampling, and no mipmaps, but for some reason even like that I need to reduce the size of the final tile UV rect so as to have a boundary of what seems to be 2 pixels. I am still trying to figure why.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment. if you're using instanced rendering then your code doesn't seem like it could be similar to the code above. The code above draws a single quad. not a quad per tile, just one quad period. I'm glad you found a solution

Comment: Draw 1 quad, 100 quads, not much of a difference, just more setup. My solution turned out to not be so generic, if I zoom out more so that the tiles get smaller and smaller, I need a bigger and bigger boundary. It really feels like a mipmapping issue, but the texture has no mipmaps. Still looking into it.

Comment: I spent so much time on this, I was just planning to finally ditch the texture atlas and reorganize all of the code for a draw call per texture....and then I remembered I told myself to try to turn off antialiasing for the WebGL context. That was it...so a big facepalm. Thanks for the answer regardless. While ultimately it doesn't answer my question, I feel like it's a good resource for newcomers to tilemap rendering, so I accepted it.

Comment: Ok, well, antialiasing is not off above

Comment: Is it running with an arbitrary-sized canvas? mine stretches across the whole window. If it is, and there are no artifacts (when zoomed out), then it really is a mystery to me.

Comment: That being said, I already experienced different drivers doing different things with boundary sampling, so it could also be that.

Comment: This example works great, until disabling rotation.  I changed the rotation line to `const rotation = 0;` and as soon as I run that I start seeing the line artifacts again.

Comment: @nekofluxλ, updated the shader to clamp. Maybe no seams now? I couldn't see the seams before so I can't test

Comment: @gman Your most recent changes seem to have fixed the issue. Thanks!!  In case it's helpful, I'm on macos, and was replicating this problem on latest stable chrome, safari, and firefox prior to your fix.

Comment: I'm planning to go through your working example line-by-line with a fine-toothed comb, but is there any place where you have a write-up on how this works?   I've looked at 2 other webgl tilemap shaders written by very smart people and neither one of them handles tile bleeding, so I'd be very interested to read any material you have on how this shader actually works.

Comment: There isn't a ton to know. The shader looks up which tile from the tilemap texture. Those are stored 4 bytes per tile. 2 are the ID of the tile x,y so if the tile is the 3rd image from the left and 4th row down then xy = 2, 3. Another byte is the flags (xflp, yflip, xyswap). From the tile ID you can compute texture coords for that tile. To stop the bleeding you need to bound those coords a 0.5 pixel on each side. Since blending happens between pixel centers, if you go to the right of the center of the last pixel in the tile you'll start to get colors from the next tile.

Comment: [this diagram](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-textures.html#magfilter) might help?