# How to increase FPS in javascript canvas? I use DrawImage to draw 2000 textures on screen, they use 2 atlas textures

Tags: javascript, optimization, 2d, webgl, tile

I'm struggling to get more than 90 fps, making 2d game with tiles and objects like trees, and performance is pretty bad, considering it's only 2000 objects. On C I had similar problems with 3d when each my quad was separate drawcall, so at 80k drawcalls I was getting ~80 FPS in 3D, and when switched to VBO I was started getting 300+, but here it's choking at 100x50 tilemap (I don't render tiles outside of screen, so it's solid 100x50) + 50% of tiles having a tree.

Is there any way to optimize rendering like lists, arrays or VBO in opengl?

Comment: Are you asking for OpenGL or WebGL? You tagged the question `javascript` and `webgl` but you asked "Is there any way to optimize ... in opengl?". Those 2 things are entirely unrelated. If you're asking for OpenGL you'll get different answers than for WebGL. Also what **exactly** are you trying to do. Ideally put your code in the question so we can see. Optimizing 5000 particles is a different problem than a grid of tiles which is different than 5000 sprites, etc...

Comment: Also you mentioned tilemap. There's [an example of drawing a tilemap in one draw call here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465085/128511) which will be much much faster than 5000 draw calls.

Comment: Sounds like you are using HTML5 canvas. You should look into the WebGL api instead. The API is similar to OpenGL. If you want to use a library for 2D WebGL, use PixiJS