# webgl tilemap rendering incorrect UV calculation

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to render a tile map onto a single quad.

My approach uses a "tile map" texture in which each pixel stores the X and Y indices of a tile inside a tile set.

When rendering a fragment, the idea is to:

1. Sample the "tile map" texture using vertex texture coordinates
2. Retrieve the X and Y indices from the R and G channels of the texture
3. **Calculate the UVs of the selected tile**
4. Use the UVs to sample the texture atlas

I'm having issues with getting #3 to work.

Here is the shader code I'm trying to use to render this:

vertex

```c
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 uVIEW;
uniform mat4 uPROJECTION;

uniform mat3 uMODEL;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPOSITION;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTEXCOORD;

out vec2 vTEXCOORD;

void main()
{
    // flip uv and pass it to fragment shader
    vTEXCOORD = vec2(aTEXCOORD.x, 1.0f - aTEXCOORD.y);
    // transform vertex position
    vec3 transformed = uMODEL * vec3(aPOSITION, 1.0);
    gl_Position = uPROJECTION * uVIEW * vec4(transformed.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

fragment

```c
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
precision mediump usampler2D;

uniform usampler2D uMAP;
uniform sampler2D uATLAS;
uniform vec2 uATLAS_SIZE;

in vec2 vTEXCOORD;

out vec4 oFRAG;

void main()
{
    // sample "tile map" texture
    vec4 data = vec4(texture(uMAP, vTEXCOORD));
    // calculate UV
    vec2 uv = (data.xy * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE) + (vTEXCOORD * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE);
    // sample the tileset
    oFRAG = texture(uATLAS, uv);
}
```

I believe this is the culprit:

```c
vec2 uv = (data.xy * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE) + (vTEXCOORD * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE);
```

The formula here is `uv = (tile_xy_indices * tile_size) + (texcoord * tile_size)`, where:

- `texcoord` is the vertex uv (the standard [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1])
- `tile_xy_indices` are the X,Y coordinates of the tile in the tileset
- `tile_size` is the normalized size of one tile in the tileset

So if I have the values `texcoord = (0, 0)`, `tile_xy_indices = (7, 7)`, `tile_size = (32 / 1024, 32 / 1024)`, then the UV for this fragment should be `(0.21875, 0.21875)`, and if `texcoord = (1, 1)`, then it should be `(0.25, 0.25)`. These values seem correct to me, **why do they produce the wrong result, and how do I fix it?**

Here is some extra context:

- Tile map texture (exaggerated colors):

[image: tilemap texture]

- Expected result (minus the grid lines):

[image: tilemap]

- Actual result:

[image: result]

Comment: FYI: there is no reason to pass `uATLAS_SIZE`. Just call `vec2 ATLAS_SIZE = vec2(textureSize(uATLAS, 0))` to get the size of the texture

Comment: Also FYI: There is a working tiler in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465085/128511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is conflating 3 things in these 2 lines

```
// sample "tile map" texture
vec4 data = vec4(texture(uMAP, vTEXCOORD));
// calculate UV
vec2 uv = (data.xy * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE) + (vTEXCOORD * 32.0 / uATLAS_SIZE);
// sample the tileset
```

The first one, for the entire quad you're drawing, goes over your entire tilemap. That's probably not what you want. Usually apps that use a tilemap want to show a portion of it, not the entire thing.

The second problem is the second line needs to know how many pixels a tile will cover, not how many pixels a tile is. In other words if you have a 32x32 tile and you draw it in 4x4 pixels then your texture coordinate need to go from 0.0 to 1.0 across that tile in 4 pixels, not in 32 pixels.

A 3rd problem is dividing by 32 will not go across a 32pixel tile unless there are 32 tiles across the texture. Imagine you have a single tile is 32x32 pixels but there 8x4 tiles in your tile set. You need go from 0 to 1 across 1/8th and 1/4th not across 1/32

[This answer implements a tilemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465085/128511)

Effectively it uses 2 matrices. One to draw the quad which being a quad could be rotated, scaled, projected in 3D etc, but let's just say the normal thing for a tilemap would be to just draw a quad that covers the canvas.

The second is a texture matrix (or tile matrix) where each unit is 1 tile. So given, a 0 to 1 quad you compute a matrix to expand and rotate that quad on to the quad above.

Let's say you don't rotate, you still need to decide how many tiles to draw across and down the quad. If you wanted 4 tiles across the quad and 3 tiles down then you you'd set the scale to x=4 and y=3.

This way, automatically, every tile goes from 0 to 1 in its own space. Or maybe to put it another way, tile 2x7 goes from 2.0<->3.0 in U and 7.0<->8.0 in V. We can then look up from the map tile 2,7 and use `fract` to cover that tile in the space that tile occupies in the quad.

```js
const vs = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 uVIEW;
uniform mat4 uPROJECTION;
uniform mat4 uMODEL;

uniform mat4 uTEXMATRIX;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 aPOSITION;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 aTEXCOORD;

out vec2 vTEXCOORD;

void main()
{
    vTEXCOORD = (uTEXMATRIX * aTEXCOORD).xy;
    gl_Position = uPROJECTION * uVIEW * uMODEL * aPOSITION;
}
`;

const fs = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
precision mediump usampler2D;

uniform usampler2D uMAP;
uniform sampler2D uATLAS;
uniform vec2 uTILESET_SIZE; // how many tiles across and down the tileset

in vec2 vTEXCOORD;

out vec4 oFRAG;

void main()
{
    // the integer portion of vTEXCOORD is the tilemap coord
    ivec2 mapCoord = ivec2(vTEXCOORD);
    uvec4 data = texelFetch(uMAP, mapCoord, 0);
    
    // the fractional portion of vTEXCOORD is the UV across the tile
    vec2 texcoord = fract(vTEXCOORD);

    vec2 uv = (vec2(data.xy) + texcoord) / uTILESET_SIZE;
    
    // sample the tileset
    oFRAG = texture(uATLAS, uv);
}
`;

const tileWidth = 32;
const tileHeight = 32;
const tilesAcross = 8;
const tilesDown = 4;

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
if (!gl) alert('need WebGL2');

// compile shaders, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
// gl.createBuffer, bindBuffer, bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  aPOSITION: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      0, 1,
      
      0, 1,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
    ],
  },
  aTEXCOORD: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      0, 1,
      
      0, 1,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
    ],
  },
});

function r(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return min + (max - min) * Math.random();
}

// make some tiles
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = tileWidth * tilesAcross;
ctx.canvas.height = tileHeight * tilesDown;
ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

const f = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~';
for (let y = 0; y < tilesDown; ++y) {
  for (let x = 0; x < tilesAcross; ++x) {
    const color = `hsl(${r(360) | 0},${r(50,100)}%,50%)`;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    const tx = x * tileWidth;
    const ty = y * tileHeight;
    ctx.fillRect(tx, ty, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.fillText(f.substr(y * 8 + x, 1), tx + tileWidth * .5, ty + tileHeight * .5); 
  }
}
document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);

const tileTexture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
 src: ctx.canvas,
 minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

// make a tilemap
const mapWidth = 400;
const mapHeight = 300;
const tilemap = new Uint32Array(mapWidth * mapHeight);
const tilemapU8 = new Uint8Array(tilemap.buffer);
const totalTiles = tilesAcross * tilesDown;
for (let i = 0; i < tilemap.length; ++i) {
  const off = i * 4;
  // mostly tile 9
  const tileId = r(4) < 1 
      ? (r(totalTiles) | 0)
      : 9;
  tilemapU8[off + 0] = tileId % tilesAcross;
  tilemapU8[off + 1] = tileId / tilesAcross | 0;
}

const mapTexture = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  internalFormat: gl.RGBA8UI,
  src: tilemapU8,
  width: mapWidth,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

function ease(t) {
  return Math.cos(t) * .5 + .5;
}

function lerp(a, b, t) {
  return a + (b - a) * t;
}

function easeLerp(a, b, t) {
  return lerp(a, b, ease(t));
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds;
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);  

  // these mats affects where the quad is drawn
  const projection = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
  const view = m4.identity();
  const model =
  m4.scaling([gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 1]);
 
  const tilesAcrossQuad = 10;//easeLerp(.5, 2, time * 1.1);
  const tilesDownQuad = 5;//easeLerp(.5, 2, time * 1.1);
  
  // scroll position in tiles
  // set this to 0,0 and the top left corner of the quad
  // will be the start of the map.
  const scrollX = time % mapWidth;
  const scrollY = 0;//time % (mapHeight * tileHeight);
  
  const tmat = m4.identity();
  // sets where in the map to look at in tile coordinates
  // so 3,4 means start drawing 3 tiles over, 4 tiles down
  m4.translate(tmat, [scrollX, scrollY, 0], tmat);
  // sets how many tiles to display
  m4.scale(tmat, [tilesAcrossQuad, tilesDownQuad, 1], tmat);

  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    uPROJECTION: projection,
    uVIEW: view,
    uMODEL: model,
    uTEXMATRIX: tmat,
    uMAP: mapTexture,
    uATLAS: tileTexture,
    uTILESET_SIZE: [tilesAcross, tilesDown],
  });
  
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: `for the entire quad you're drawing, goes over your entire tilemap. That's probably not what you want.` - this is what i want. I came across your answer, but I couldn't apply it to what I'm doing.

Comment: The quad I'm drawing is scaled to `[columns*tilesize, rows*tilesize]`. I have a tileset (texture atlas), containing unique tiles. Then there's the tilemap, which is just a list of tile indices, and I want to use the indices to sample the tileset. I want to render the entire tilemap at once, and then translate/scale/rotate the quad as required.

Comment: In the OP, you can see the rendered tilemap texture. All I want to do is for each tile in the tilemap, sample the tile at X and Y in the tileset. I see in the answer you linked, you're doing some kind of transformation to the texture coords, but I have no idea what it does. It isn't commented, and the variable names are cryptic...

Comment: I updated the answer. The texture matrix decides what part of the tilemap to display on your quad. It's in tile coordinates and its multiplying the standard 0 to 1 texture coordinates. So, if you passed in the identity for uTEXMATRIX you'd get the first tile in the map drawn across the entire quad. If you passed in a scaling matrix of (x=4, y=3) you'd get 4 tiles across and 3 tiles down the quad. If passed in a translation of x=6,y=4 then the tile at the top left of the quad would be tile 6x4 from the map.